# Java Intellj: How to automate java project again a list of test files as program arguments and compare output?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, testng

I use Java Intellj IDEA 14.0.2 with compile for a school project name "crux.Compiler".

I got a list of 30 test files like: test01.crx, test02.crx, test03.crx ... test30.crx

Also a list of 30 expected correct output files: test01.out, test02.out, test03.out ... test30.out

I know that when try to run in IDE with 1 argument test file only in Edit Configuration:

[image]

The behind-the-scene command is like this:

"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -classpath /home/linuxuser/Desktop/Lab1_Scanner/out/production/lab1_scanner crux.Compiler test05.crx"

Is there a way to automate all these 30 test file with all 30 expected output files in Intellj IDEA 14?

I try to look into unit test suit like: JUnit , TestNG but not find what I need!

Can someone point me to the right place or help me out with the configurate the IDEA ?

Any help is greatly appreciate :)

Comment: When you say "automate" do you mean executing all 30 tests with one command or something else? Also how do you validate the test results against the expected outputs?

Comment: I mean except them one-by-one with the argument "test01.crx", "test02.crx" ... etc

Comment: Also how do you validate the test results against the expected outputs? --> I compare them by eye-ball the output program with "test01.out" ... !

Comment: Then just create 30 run configurations, one for each test file. That's if you want to use IDEA. In bash it would be achieved with a one line script.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to perform this kind of automation using IntelliJ IDEA features. You need to modify your test application so that it would iterate through the input file names and compare them with the expected output data.

You can use JUnit or TestNG for that, but you don't have to; you can simply continue using a plain Java application that would, instead of taking the file name as an argument, calculate it based on the pattern that your input files have.